# How to change cube's face color when click an object in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

With Three.js, I want to change the color of face of the first object I clicked.

Here is my function.

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    var i = 0;
    var faceIndex = parseInt(intersects[i].faceIndex / (2 * dimensions * dimensions));
    intersects[i].object.material.color.set(0xffffff);
    var nextColor = colors[parseInt(Math.random() * 6)];
    intersects[i].object.geometry.faces[faceIndex * 2].color.setHex(nextColor);
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

First I got the object, and calculate the face index. And I try to change the color, but it doesn't work. How to fix this function?

Comment: Lee Stemkoski's [example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Click.html) will help. Though it's r60, but it's useful anyway.

Comment: @prisoner849 It works! Thank you!